# is iOS VoIP push payload similar to the payload of silent notifications?

Tags: ios, swift, voip, pushkit, usernotifications

I have an app that gets silent notification from server (with UserNotifications framework) to start some process. It's work fine. For some purposes, I have to implement also VoIP push (with PushKit framework) in my app.

Which changes in the the payload (except the token) should I insert? 
Can I send the same payload with only replace the UserNotifications token with the PushKit token?

Comment: try same payload with voIP token & voIP pem file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, you can send same payload, VOIP payload are always by default silent. And all types of notification payload goes in json only.

For example

```
$body['aps'] = array(
'content-available'=> 1,
'alert' => $message,
'sound' => 'default',
'badge' => 0,
);
```

You can append json payload as per your requirement.

Once you get payload in `didReceiveIncomingPushWithPayload` you can convert in array and or dictionary.

Refer more details

https://github.com/hasyapanchasara/PushKit_SilentPushNotification